# Accessing host machine as localhost from a Docker container when building the image

Tags: docker

I want to copy a file in my localhost to the container.

```
RUN wget http://127.0.0.1/wso2/wso2esb-5.0.0.zip
```

Im trying to parameterize the location (IP). For testing I'm trying to point it to the localhost. When running the container we can bind the ip address to the host with --net='host' . But how can I access the host machine when I build the image. Or is there a default IP for the host machine in the build stage ?

Comment: you can use `docker cp` to copy files from your server/localhost to a running container. This is fine for testing purposes. The best solution is to perform a `COPY` in a dockerfile or mount the volume to your container using `-v`. This is dependent of your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use **docker cp** ?

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

Comment: I want to parameterize the location(ip) to download the file. So for testing I'm using the machines localhost.